# using 2 loops in PHP foreach(...)

Tags: php, foreach

I have this PHP foreach loop:

```
foreach($emails_list as $email)
```

but i want to do something like

```
foreach($emails_list as $email and $forename_list as $forename)
```

my code above the foreach loop is:

```
$sql2="SELECT * from contacts where company_sequence = '".$customersequence."' and contactstatus = '' ";
            $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
            {
                $emails_list[] = $result2["email"];
            }
```

si i want to be able to include `$result["forename"];` within the loop too

will the above work to make 2 loops?

Comment: If the arrays are in the same order you could use `array_combine` to create one single array.

Comment: WHat are you trying to do? What do your arrays look like? Why do you need to access both in the same loop? Explain the actual problem, not how you're trying to resolve it. Perhaps an SPL multipleiterator might help; but unless you explain we can't know what to advise, only guess

Comment: And the $forename_list? Do the entries in that array match those you're reading from mail contacts? Are they from the same `contacts` table? If so, why not read them both at the same time?

Comment: You could use a multidimensional array instead of two seperate arrays. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if understand, but try use `for` instead:

```
$emails_list = array("01@gmail.com", "02@gmail.com", "03@gmail.com", "04@gmail.com");
$forename_list = ("01 something", "02 something", "03 something", "04 something");

if($emails_list == $forename_list){
  $count = count($emails_list); 

  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    echo 'Email: '.$emails_list[$i].', Name: '.$forename_list[$i];
  }
} else { echo 'Troubles'; }
```

Comment: You should not use `count ($emails list)` inside of the loop init for performance improvements

Comment: What is your suggest, instead of `count` ?

Comment: `$count_temp = count ($emails_list);`
Then use `$count_temp` in the loop, so it won't be counted again every time you loop

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do this in foreach in a one statment

for this use for loop like

```
for ($i=0;$i<=count($emails_list); $i++) {
 echo $emails_list[$i];
 echo $forename_list[$i];
}
```

Comment: You should not use `count ($emails list)` inside of the loop init for performance improvements

Comment: You'll run into trouble if $forename_list is smaller than $emails_list

Answer (score 0):

All the examples listed with a basic for loop will work fine for numeric arrays, however what about associative arrays?
The best way to do this would be something like the following:

```
$arr_1 = array( 'foo'=>'bar', 'fizz'=>'bang' );
$arr_2 = array( 'hello'=>1, 2=>'world' );

$array_size = count( $arr_1 ); // NOTE: This assumes the arrays are of the same size.

// Reset the internal array pointers
reset( $arr_1 );
reset( $arr_2 );

for ($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++ ) {
    $first_array_element = current( $arr_1 );
    $second_array_element = current( $arr_2 );

    // code here

    next( $arr_1 );
    next( $arr_2 );
}
```

This will handle both associative and numeric arrays.